# Strange characters using std :: cin

Tags: c++, xcode

I have been developing an application in C++ with Xcode 6.3.2 under OSX Yosemite and whenever I ask the operator to enter a parameter with the code below, it works fine, except if at some point the operator makes a mistake while typing and corrects his entry using the arrows on the keyboard. If he does so, this is the output he gets :

```
Please enter the name of the object : test
You entered : test
```

Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    char *object_name = new char [20];
    cout << "\nPlease enter the name of the object : ";
    cin >> object_name;
    cout << "You entered : " << object_name;
}
```

Following @awesomeyi and @NathanOliver, I am now using std::string but I am still getting the same problem.

Here is the new code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main( int argc, char** argv )

{
    string object_name;
    cout << "\nPlease enter the name of the object : ";
    cin >> object_name;
    cout << "You entered : " << object_name;
}
```

Any idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not `std::string`?

Comment: I am using std::char because I need to compare the entry of the operator with the std::char output of a function I did not write and can't modify.

Comment: @Nano If you have a function that returns a `char *` you can still compare that to a `std::string` as it will be converted for you.

Comment: Thanks, I am now using `std::string` but I have the same problem. (See new code above).

Comment: not putting this as an answer as I can repo since I don;t have OSX but More than likely using the arrow keys is inserting Unicode characters into the the stream that `cin` cannot handle.  You can change from using `cin` to `wcin` which will handle wide character input and you can store those wide characters into a `std::wstring`

Comment: alternatively you can check in a loop if you're dealing with printable or control character. But Nathan's suggestions looks way more elegant.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I am sorry to answer this late but, I get the same result with `wcin`... Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it for the latest version of Xcode on El Capitan on my Mac and with Dev C++ version 5.9.2, apparently there is no problem with inserting characters into the stream using Dev C++, but the swapping of numbers and insertion of '?' character is prevalent in the output stream of Xcode. As @NathanOliver mentioned, I tried wcin aswell. The problem seems to exist in the Xcode compiler only.